# GWT 2.7 Datepicker is not anchored to the DateBox in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, datepicker

I am using GWT 2.7 and I noticed today that when using Chrome (version 61.0.3163.100) the datepicker is no longer anchored to the DateBox when I scroll. I scroll down select the date and the datepicker appears further up the page. If I scroll farr enough down the datepicker is off the page. This does not occur in MS Edge or IE 11. I do not know when this first started; however, I am sure that it can not be more than a few days. Is there a compatibility setting that I need to add please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9542
Already fixed and waiting for the next (2.8.2) release (soon)